# Jquery load file to execute when DOM is loaded (not wait for images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using this

```
$('#message').load('/searchresult.php<? echo $requeststring; ?>', function() {
  $('#searching').hide();
});
```

To load a page with search results, however it is very slow because it does not display before the images are loaded aswell. How can I display the contents of searchresult as soon as the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Where have you put the above code?

Comment: `$.fn.load` would not wait for the `onload` event to fire, it executes **immediately after** server returns the full content, so the slow may be caused by your network latency and speed, not the `onload` event firing time.

Comment: have you tried using $('#message').not('img').load() ??? I am not sure of this, its just a suggestion

Comment: @MandeepJain seems to be faster at least, thanks!

Comment: I still havent tested that. let me know if that works. I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment, I think the problem might be that you have a callback function inside `.load()`, so you could try this:

```
$('#message').load(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/searchresult.php<? echo $requeststring; ?>',
        success: function (result) {
             $('#searching').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

PS jQuery API doc says `If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.` (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

PPS My guess is that it takes time because of the way each function is processed one at a time.

Comment: The question is not about `load-event` but http://api.jquery.com/load/ which is a different beast.

Comment: Yes sorry, didn't notice. I've updated the answer, I hope it helps, let me know!